# GHashTable that using uint64_t as key and a struct as value

Tags: c, linux, hashtable, glibc

I am studying the `GHashTable`. Though there are already some examples in Stackoverflow, they are just some common case. So I am still not sure how to implement my requirements and decide to ask for help.
I want to use a `uint64_t` as key and a `struct` as value. I find that there is no such built-in hash function in `GLib`. There is just a `g_int64_hash()`. Though the key is `uint64_t`, it will just be about 52 bits. So I think `gint64` is OK. But I see some examples using `GINT_TO_POINTER()` to convert the value (and sometimes they didn't). So just be confused about this.
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in [`ghash.c`](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/ghash.c#L1910) how `g_int64_hash` and `g_int64_equal` are implemented:

```
...
gboolean
g_int64_equal (gconstpointer v1,
               gconstpointer v2)
{
  return *((const gint64*) v1) == *((const gint64*) v2);
}
...
guint
g_int64_hash (gconstpointer v)
{
  return (guint) *(const gint64*) v;
}
...
```

You can write your won `uint64_t_hash` and `uint64_equal` similarly:

```
gboolean
uint64_t_equal (gconstpointer v1,
                gconstpointer v2)
{
  return *((const uint64_t*) v1) == *((const uint64_t*) v2);
}

guint
uint64_t_hash (gconstpointer v)
{
  return (guint) *(const uint64_t*) v;
}
```

See an example:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

/* the value structure */
typedef struct __MyStruct
{
  int a;
  int b;
} MyStruct;

/* the hash equality function */
static gboolean
uint64_t_equal (gconstpointer v1,
                gconstpointer v2)
{
  return *((const uint64_t*) v1) == *((const uint64_t*) v2);
}

/* the hash function */
static guint
uint64_t_hash (gconstpointer v)
{
  return (guint) *(const uint64_t*) v;
}

/* the hash function */
static void
print_hash(gpointer key,
           gpointer value,
           gpointer user_data)
{
  printf("%" PRIu64 " = {%d, %d}\n",
    *(uint64_t*) key, ((MyStruct *) value)->a, ((MyStruct *) value)->b);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GHashTable *hash;

  /* key => value */
  uint64_t k1 = 11; MyStruct s1 = {1, 11};
  uint64_t k2 = 22; MyStruct s2 = {2, 22};
  uint64_t k3 = 33; MyStruct s3 = {3, 33};

  hash = g_hash_table_new(uint64_t_hash, uint64_t_equal);

  /* insert values */
  g_hash_table_insert(hash, &k1, &s1);
  g_hash_table_insert(hash, &k2, &s2);
  g_hash_table_insert(hash, &k3, &s3);

  /* iterate over the values in the hash table */
  g_hash_table_foreach(hash, print_hash, NULL);
  g_hash_table_destroy(hash);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I lack the ability to find out something inside.:)Then should I call g_hash_talbe_insert() like this?
`uint64_t key;
struct A val;
g_hash_table_insert(table, &key, &val);` or `g_hash_table_insert(table, key, &val);`

Comment: @tamlok The first is correct, `insert` expect a pointer in both key and value. OK, I added a complete example.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But when I use `g_hash_table_lookup(hash, &k1)`, it returns NULL. Why?

Comment: @tamlok It works fine to me, make sure that `k1` and `s1` are alive, you may need to allocate them on the heap and not the stack if there will die.

Comment: Yes, it works! I just made a foolish mistake. I used `if (!result) { print(result); } else { print("lookup returns NULL"); }`. Thanks very much again for your timely and patient guidance again! :)

Comment: Hi @tamlok,
Should that be okay to create hash value from uint64_t to guint (which I think is 32-bit unsigned integer)? Will it create enough and unique hash when you have large number of data in hash table (having keys > 32 bit values)??