# Search HashTable not by unique key

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable, glib

I have a struct comprising a key and a trile of integers:

```
struct MyStruct
{
guint32 key;
guint64 field1;
guint64 field2
guint64 field3;
};
```

which I need to store into some kind of dictionarty structure. I have chosen a GHashTable (glib).

MyStruct member key is unique, therfore I chose to use that as the key. However I need to retrieve each struct instance by doing a search over field1, and possibly over field1 and field2.

Please find below my hash and equal functions.

```
static guint32
my_struct_oid_hash(gconstpointer k)
{
    my_struct *my_data = (my_struct *)k;

    return my_data->key;
}


static gint
my_struct_oid_equal(gconstpointer k1, gconstpointer k2)
{
    my_struct *my_data1;
    my_struct *my_data2;

    my_data1 = (my_struct *)k1;
    my_data2 = (my_struct *)k2;

    return ((my_data1->field1 == my_data2->field1) && (my_data1->field2 == my_data2->field2));
}
```

The problem is that both the lookup and lookup_extenede functions always returns NULL.

```
my_struct* my_key;

    my_key->key=0; //set key to 0 just for the sake of inizializazion. It is not used for the comparison in the my_struct_oid_equal function.

    my_key->field1=1;
    my_key->field2=2;


my_data = ((my_struct*)(g_hash_table_lookup(my_hashtable, my_key)));
```

What am I doing wrong?

I changed the last line of my_struct_oid_hash to

```
return ((guint32)*((const my_struct *)my_data));
```

and I tried the approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298327/ghashtable-that-using-uint64-t-as-key-and-a-struct-as-value), but I got the following compiling errors:

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const my_struct' to 'guint32'
warning C4033: 'my_struct_oid_hash' must return a value.
```

Howvever I do not believe that is the way to go as casting my_struct to guint would not make much sense.

I have also thought that a hashtable may not be the best solution as I am not searching by the key value. In this case, apart from GList, what would be the other options with direct access in glib?

Comment: have you thought about Boost.MultiIndex?

Comment: @dmg. I can't use it. I have to use glib. It is a constraint of the project.

Comment: @geraldCelente How are you inserting these structs into the hash table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are getting a NULL because you are looking for a struct, not a key. Instead of:

```
my_data = ((my_struct*)(g_hash_table_lookup(my_hashtable, my_key)));
```

Use

```
my_data = ((my_struct*)(g_hash_table_lookup(my_hashtable, my_key->key)));
```

Or

```
my_data = ((my_struct*)(g_hash_table_lookup(my_hashtable, 0)));
```

Anyway, looks like you want a three data value as key (key, field1 and field2), so you need another way to store your key, because GHashTable only use one parameter for the key...

Perhaps a string key with the three values, separated by a string like "|" (i.e. "0|1|2"), parsing the data in the hash equal function.

Hope it help.

Comment: Or perhaps I'm missing something, could you please write your "g_hash_table_new" code?